# Loop to create JSON object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

just trying to loop thru my Story model.. and create JSON object and insert it into Call and send it.. But i'm not sure how to loop thru Stories..

I've done this:

```
@stories = Array.new

Story.where(newsletter_id: current_user.selected_newsletter) do |story|
 @stories << {
   :title => story.title,
   :image_url => story.image_url
 }
end
```

and i'm trying ti insert the loop to this JSON OBJECT

```
"message" => {
   "attachment" => {
      "type" => "template",
      "payload" => {
        "template_type" => "generic",
        "elements" => [{this is the array}]
      }
   }
}
```

The array with multiple stories should looks like this:

```
[
  {
  "title" => "title....1",
  "image" => "image....1"
  },
  {
  "title" => "title....2",
  "image" => "image....3"
  }
  ....
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
@stories = Story.where(newsletter_id: current_user.selected_newsletter)
                .select(:title, 'image_url as image').as_json(except: :id)
```

And then:

```
{
  "message" => {
    "attachment" => {
      "type" => "template",
      "payload" => {
        "template_type" => "generic",
        "elements" => @stories
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Right, i tried that like that and it wont make the call.. i think its because the array is with ids and there should be just a title and image : `{"id"=>nil, "title"=>"...", "image_url"=>"..."}`.. thats what i get but the array is perfect thanks for that a lot!

Comment: @LiborZahrádka: there are just `title` and `image_url`. Do you need it to be `image` or `image_url?`

Comment: U are right.. i have to make a call with `image` but in db im saving it as `image_url`

Comment: Any idea how to exclude id attr from that array?
Because even when i dont selected id the id is still there as nil value